# Is this statement true for all conservative forces or just attractive conservative forces?

Tags: energy-conservation, potential, potential-energy

'Change in potential energy is always equal to the negative of the work done by a conservative force.'

Comment: When a force acts on an object, the object doesn't know if it is attractive or repulsive.

Comment: I think the definition is **Change in potential energy of a system is defined as the negative of work done by internal conservative forces of the system**.

Comment: Swami: Yes, _if_ the potential energy and work refer to the _same_ (attractive and/or repulsive) conservative force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all conservative forces. As an example, coulombic force on two like charges is repulsive still we have your statement as true and Coulombic interaction is Conservative.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is true for electrostatics, which can be repulsive.
So, it's true for all conservative forces.
(This statement is part of the motivation for the existence of a potential energy function, without regard to whether the force is attractive.)